# Facebook bot don't send notification to user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook page like a bot, It works fine but I noticed that messages from the bot doesn't send like notifications on mobile. I found bot that I receive notifications from. How to configure it on my bots? Any suggestions what should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use bot framework and I found that we didn't add field to message for facebook. After adding this field notification begun to show

```
message.channelData = { notification_type: 'REGULAR' };
```